# iOS - Can UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext be used outside drawRect?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgcontextref

I want to dynamically change the current CGContextRef according to different user actions? Is this possible or is its modification only possible within `drawRect:` of a view instance? What happens when I call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` outside `drawRect:` and are there any limitations in doing so, is this recommended? Any possible implications I need to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs the graphics context is only set just before this function is called. This means that if this function is not called it won't be set and if you don't make the system call it again (never do this yourself for that reason) it won't be there either.

Use one of these functions to force the view back into drawRect:

```
setNeedsDisplay:
setNeedsDisplayInRect:
```

It doesn't mean you can only do stuff inside drawRect however. This context is sort of globally available at that moment and you can call clean separate functions or even classes for drawing things. Passing the reference to those functions is a clean way to do it.